# How to use an interface property in my RestController to return data in my request handlers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I have declared an interface as a property of my `@RestController`.  That interface just has a few fields/setters/getters.

The implementation of the RestController and GetMapping look like this:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AccountController {
    private AccountStoreInterface store;

    @GetMapping(value="/account")
    public Account readAccount(@RequestParam("id") String id) throws AccountNotFoundException {

        Account a = store.getAccount(id); 
        if (a.getId().isEmpty()) {
            throw new AccountNotFoundException();
        }

        return a;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccountNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(NOT_FOUND)
    public @ResponseBody String handleAccountNotFoundException(AccountNotFoundException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage(); }

    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public @ResponseBody String handleNullPointerException(NullPointerException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

The interface declaration looks like this:

```
public interface AccountStoreInterface {
    public Account getAccount(String id) throws AccountNotFoundException;
    public Account setAccount(String id, Account account) throws AccountConflictException;
}
```

I would like to test this using `spring-boot-starter-test` and `junit4`.  I expect the following test to return a 500 because I have not passed any store object that implements my interface so it should throw a `NullPointerException`.

How do I configure my unit tests in order to test the `500` and `404` status codes?

Right now, the below test actually fails because the returned status is 200, which I don't understand how junit gets to.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AccountController.class)
public class TestAccountController {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @MockBean
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Test
    public void testGetAccountNotFound() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/account?id={id}", "test-account-id-123")
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .characterEncoding("UTF-8"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

Comment: STart by removing the wac field (you're not using it anywhere), and the accountController field (you're not using it anywhere, and it must not be a mock bean: you want to test your actual controller, not a mock controller). You shouldn't expect a 404: the resource does exist You should expect a 500 error dur to a NullPointerException. But what's the point in testing code that is guaranteed to be incorrect?

Comment: I just really want to declare an object that implements my account store and then test the returned JSON, but I'm not able to make it return the status code I expect.  I'm just started with java and spring...  the test for the GET request would start by inserting something into the store and then i would use mockMvc to perform the GET request and check the output.  that's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: First of all, clear the point in your mind that if you are writing a unit test or integration test, Because you are using `Autowired` and `SpringRunner`, it loads ApplicationContext and hence it is integration test. But you are using `MockBean` too. Mocking is used in unit testing. So correct these things and then re-run your tests.

Comment: Why should it. You are mocking your controller so there is no functionality being called. You should mock the `AccountStoreInterface` instead and `@Autowire` the controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum that sounds like what I'm trying to do.  I'm just really confused by all the different annotations and what they do.  Coming from other environment I find it a bit difficult.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Basically remove everything for now and only leave the `MockMvc` with `@Autowired`. This will give you the result you want.